# How to apply my code for use Ctrl+A for select All?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to apply my code for use `Ctrl+A` for select All ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Fp4sJ/806/

First, fill number `EG: 333.44` into input, Then press key Ctrl+A.

Why not select All data in input, How can i apply ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
 $(".allownumericwithdecimal").on("keypress keyup blur",function (event) {
            //this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
     $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
            if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });

});
</script>

<input type="text" name="numeric" class='allownumericwithdecimal'>
```

Comment: it works if you take out that javascript, or just use keypress. use an input type=number instead of off-sides JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the "keyup" trigger from the event here:

```
$(".allownumericwithdecimal").on("keypress keyup blur",function (event) {
```

Leave it like this

```
$(".allownumericwithdecimal").on("keypress blur",function (event) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```js
event.preventDefault();
```